# Как происходит передача аргумента лямбда-выражению?

Tags: c++, lambda, лямбда-выражение

Изучая лямбда-выражения, столкнулся со стойким непониманием и безрезультативными попытками самостоятельно разобраться с передачей аргументов лямбда выражениям.

Я знаю, что лямбда может принимать аргумент, если после объявления или где-либо после написать скобки: `(arg);`.

Также лямбда может захватывать значения перемемнных `[=]`, `[x]` и т.д.

Однако, как лямбда получает аргумент, имея подобную конструкцию:

`[](int n){/*do something*/}`,

если нигде после её объявления явно не вызываются "скобки со значением", нет доступных из лямбды внешних ссылок, и она ничего не захватывает?

Подскажие,  как передаются аргументы лямбда-выражениям в подобных случаях?

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    list<int> numbers;
    numbers.push_back(13);
    numbers.push_back(42);
    numbers.push_back(99);

    const list<int>::const_iterator result = 
        find_if(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(),[](int n) { return (n % 2) == 0; });

    if (result != numbers.end()) {
        cout << "The first even number in the list is " << *result << "." << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "The list contains no even numbers." << endl;
    }
}
```

Как я понмаю, лямбда-выражение имеет параметр (int n), однако не вижу где лямбда принимает этот аргумент. И не понимаю как он мог бы передаваться неявно.

```
...
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> srcVec;
    for (int val = 0; val < 10; val++)
    {
        srcVec.push_back(val);
    }

    int result =
        count_if(srcVec.begin(), srcVec.end(), [] (int _n)
        {
            return (_n % 2) == 0;
        });

    cout << result << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Как происходит подобная "неявная" передача аргументов лямбда-выражениям, имеющим параметр, но не обращающихся к внешним переменным самостоятельно через завхват или область видимости?

Может быть я не понимаю какого-то банального принципа, который совершенно тривиален, но был мной упущен? Спасибо.

Comment: find_if вызывает и передает аргумент

Comment: Странный вопрос. Если лямбда нигде не вызывается - тот аргумент передаваться не будет.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Функция `find_if`, `count_if` 3-м аргументом принимают **унарный предикат(UnaryPredicat)** - функция, которая на вход принимает один аргумент и возвращает тип bool. [Требования к предикатной функции](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Predicate).

Внутренняя реализация этих функций из стандартной библиотеки вызывает этот унарный предикат, передавая ей в качестве аргумента текущее "тестируемое значение" из коллекции.
Унарный предикатом может быть как лямбда-функция, так и любой реализованный самостоятельно функтор.

Answer (score 10):

> Однако, как лямбда получает аргумент, имея подобную конструкцию:
>
> ```
> [](int n){/*do something*/},
> ```
>
> если нигде после её объявления явно не вызываются "скобки со
>   значением"?
>
> ```
> find_if(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(),[](int n) { return (n % 2) == 0; });
> ```

На самом деле здесь все просто. Лямбду вызывает `find_if`, то есть эти "скобки со значением" находятся где-то внутри `find_if`.

Вот пример реализации `find_if` с [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
template<class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate>
InputIt find_if(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first)
    {
        if (p(*first)) // <--- Вот они скобки (вызов лямбды)
        {
            return first;
        }
    }
    return last;
}
```